# Displaying R and Python Plots Side by Side in Quarto

Tags: python, r, plot, quarto

I am attempting to display two plots in a Quarto document side by side. The issue is that one is generated through R and the other through Python. Ideally, I would like the plots to appear as they do in this document:

[image: Quarto Example]

However, this seems to only work for images created by the same method (either both plots are created in R or both are created in Python). Here's the link where I got this example from: https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/computations/rstudio.html

Additionally, here is the code that I am using the create these plots:
**R Plot:**

````
```{r, fig.show = 'hold', out.width = '50%'}
#| label: fig-r
#| fig-cap: "Car Weight Vs. MPG Scatterplot (R)"
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| column: page
library(ggplot2)

# Color Scale
mtcars$pc <- predict(prcomp(~wt + mpg, mtcars))[,1]

# Scatter Plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = pc)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 5, alpha = 0.4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "#0091ff", high = "#f0650e") +
  xlab('Weight (1,000 lbs)') +
  ylab('MPG') +
  ggtitle('Weight Vs. MPG')
```
````

**Python Plot:**

````
```{python, fig.show = 'hold', out.width = '50%'}
#| label: fig-python
#| fig-cap: "Car Weight Vs. MPG Scatterplot (Python)"
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| column: page
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars', 'datasets', cache = True).data
sns.scatterplot(x = "wt", 
                y = "mpg",
                data = mtcars).set_title('Weight Vs. MPG')
                
sns.regplot(x = mtcars['wt'], y = mtcars['mpg'], 
            fit_reg = False)
```
````

#### Updated Code:

[image: Screenshot]

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can render a document with both R and python code with the `knitr` engine specified, if you have the [`{reticulate}`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) R-package installed in your computer.

And to show plot (figures) side by side we can use [pandoc figure divs](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#figure-panels) with `layout-ncol=2`.

---

````
---
title: "R and Python"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

::: {layout-ncol=2 .column-page}

```{r}
#| label: fig-r
#| fig-cap: "Car Weight Vs. MPG Scatterplot (R)"
#| echo: false

library(ggplot2)

# Color Scale
mtcars$pc <- predict(prcomp(~wt + mpg, mtcars))[,1]

# Scatter Plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = pc)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 5, alpha = 0.4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "#0091ff", high = "#f0650e") +
  xlab('Weight (1,000 lbs)') +
  ylab('MPG') +
  ggtitle('Weight Vs. MPG')
```

```{python}
#| label: fig-python
#| fig-cap: "Car Weight Vs. MPG Scatterplot (Python)"
#| echo: false

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars', 'datasets', cache = True).data
sns.scatterplot(x = "wt", 
                y = "mpg",
                data = mtcars).set_title('Weight Vs. MPG')
                
sns.regplot(x = mtcars['wt'], y = mtcars['mpg'], 
            fit_reg = False)
```

:::
````

---

[image: side by side figure generated by R and python respectively]

---

Comment: This seems like a great solution! I've tried implementing it, but I must be doing something wrong with the pandoc figure divs part of it. The way my code is currently set up is one chunk of code for R and another for Python. I've tried a few ways of adding these pandoc figure divs but I keep getting an error saying there is a syntax error. Could you assist? I will add a screenshot of my code to the question above.

Comment: What is the complete error message you are getting?!  Check whether you are using pandoc divs syntax correctly.

Comment: After merging the code chunks into one cell similar to how you have it in your code I do not get the error, but I also don't get the graphics. Instead I get plain text as output. I have taken a screenshot of the code and output and placed it in the question above for your reference.

Comment: Can you add your yaml section? I am not seeing one. All of your code are rendered as simple text.